# How best create a property that will return an ImageSource dynamically built?

Tags: data-binding, asynchronous, properties, microsoft-metro, imagesource

In a Windows Metro application (release preview), I'm dynamically creating images from data points and use databinding to show the image.

As the image creation is quite heavy processing, I'd like it to be done in a task.
So my property is currently coded like this:

```
public ImageSource Diagram
{
    get
    {
        if (this.diagram == null)
        {
             DiagramGenerator.GetDiagram(this.DataPoints, this.Width, this.Height).ContinueWith((t) =>
             {
                 this.Diagram = t.Result;
             }
        }
        return this.diagram;
    }
    set
    {
        this.SetProperty(ref this.diagram, value);
    }
}
```

And the DiagramGenerator looks like:

```
public static async Task<ImageSource> DiagramGenerator.GetDiagram(List<DataPoint> dataPoints, int width, int height)
{
    WriteableBitmap bmp = BitmapFactory.New(width, height);

    // Build the image...

    return bmp;
}
```

In Xaml, my binding is pretty simple

```
<Image Source="{Binding Diagram}" Stretch="UniformToFill"/>
```

Unfortunately, using the code above doesn't work.

I get an exception raised in the OnPropertyChanged method (eg after this.Diagram = t.Result above): "The application called an interface that was marshalled for a different thread."

I then tried to marshall to the UI thread using:

Window.Current.Dispatcher.RunAsync(Windows.UI.Core.CoreDispatcherPriority.Norma, () => { this.Diagram = t.Result; });

But that doesn't work either because Window.Current is null!

How could fix this?

Thank you very much for your advices.

Answer (score 0):

You can grab the Window.Current.Dispatcher when you're on the UI thread and store it for use later, say when you create the Diagram object.  Alternatively, the Dispatcher is stored in DependencyObject so you can grab it out of there (ie it's in any UIElement object).